# Divs seem to be finding the wrong closing div tag but the syntax seems fine. What's wrong?

Tags: css, html

Div tags seem to be concluding on the wrong ending tag but I must've counted them a hundred times. I don't understand what's wrong. My boss says it needs to look good in Dreamweaver even though I've checked it in Mozilla, Safari and Chrome. Problem is that even though I'm using Sublime Text 2, some div tags are still showing that they conclude on the wrong closing div  tag. So it looks all screwed up in Dreamweaver. Like I said, I must've counted it a hundred times and I'm at a complete loss. Does anyone have any suggestions? And also more importantly, any explanations for why this is happening in two different text editors? It might be something really silly that I'm doing but I just don't see what it is... Any help? The problem is most notable with the first opening div tag. On the way down it says it concludes at the bottom closing tag. But on the way up it says that the closing tag's source is somewhere in the middle. I just don't get it... UPDATED WITH THE CHANGES MADE. Now it looks better but the div tags still resolve on the wrong lines. Dreamweaver no longer is throwing an error but it still resolves in a weird way.

```
        <style>

.landingWrapper{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 784px;
    display: block;
}

.blockIt {
    display: block;
}

.clearIt {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.margins {
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.introText {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#listHeading {
    background: #eceeef;
    margin: 6px 13px;
}

#camera {
    width: 354px;
    height: 380px;
}

#camera, .listWrap {
    display: inline-block;
}

.listWrap {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.benefitsList {
    width: 422px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.cameraDiv {
    width: 354px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.heading {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 430px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #eceeef;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading #listHeading{
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    background: #eceeef;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.ulBenefits li{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eceeef;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 0;
}

.ulBenefits li p{
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#headingTwo {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#secondaryText {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 714px;
}


.diagrams{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 713px;
    height: 195px;
}


.infoBox{
    border: 1px solid #eceeef;
    border-top: 10px solid #eceeef;
    width: 211px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.infoBox p {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#walkieTalkieOne {
    width: 209px;
    height: 186;
}

#walkieTalkieTwo {
    width: 210px;
    height: 186;
}
#walkieTalkieThree {
    width: 211px;
    height: 186;
}

.infoHeader {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.infoDesc{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.closer {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}

#resellerButton {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}

#resellButtLink{
    text-decoration: none;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
</style>
<div class="landingWrapper">
    <div  class="blockIt">
        <img id="hero" alt="Your CAMCORDER. DIGITAL Sound. AFFORDABLE price." src="images/hero.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="blockIt">
        <img id="headingOne" alt="Sony’s new UWP-D Series wireless mics deliver high-quality sound with digital audio processing." src="images/headerOne.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="introText" class="margins">
        <p class="margins">Now you can get the digital sound quality you want at an affordable price. With more than 50 years of microphone innovation, Sony introduces the new UWP-D wireless microphone system. Just because your project is budget-driven doesn't mean you have to compromise on sound quality.</p>
        <p class="margins">Sony's new wireless mics are the ideal audio-for-video solution that will boost the performance of even entry-level camcorders. Choose from among three packages, any of which are well-suited for ENG and field production or any budget-conscious application requiring high-quality digital audio.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearIt blockIt listWrap benefitsList">
            <div class="heading">
                <p id="listHeading" class="margins">Key Benefits:</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="ulBenefits">
                <li><p>Wide range with up to 72 channels</p></li>
                <li><p>Three separate UHF frequency blocks available</p></li>
                <li><p>USB Portable Charger w/Lithium-Ion Battery and AC adapter</p></li>
                <li><p>Sturdy metal body construction</li>
                <li><p>Digital audio processing</li>
                <li><p>A DSP compander provides superb transient response performance</p></li>
                <li><p>Wide switching RF bandwidth with 3 UHF frequency blocks available</p></li>
                <li><p>True diversity receiver for stable reception</p></li>
                <li><p>Output audio gain control on receiver</p></li>
                <li><p>Headphone output on receiver</p></li>
                <li><p>Handheld TX includes interchangeable capsule design</p></li>
                <li><p>Mic or line input on both body-pack and plug-on transmitters</p></li>
                <li><p>Sony UWP/800 Series & Legacy Analog Wireless System compatibility</p></li>
            </ul>
        <div class="blockIt cameraDiv">
            <img id="camera" alt="Camera" src="images/camera.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearIt blockIt">
        <img id="headingTwo" alt="Digital Sound Innovation for Analog Systems" src="images/headerTwo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="secondaryText" class="blockIt">
        <p  class="margins">Sony knows that exceptional sound quality is the most important issue in wireless transmission. While conventional analog systems use companders to provide dynamic range, the sound quality and transient response performance are not without flaws.</p>
        <p  class="margins">That's why Sony has developed a digitally processed sound solution that uses DSP (digital signal processing). The UWP-D Series utilizes a DSP compander that achieves high quality digital sound, all at an affordable price. DSP optimizes the audio signal processing between the transmitter and receiver, providing superb transient response performance.</p>
        <p class="margins">With easy-to-use automatic channel setting mode, clear channel and active channel scan, IR sync and unprecedented frequency coverage, you will never look at sound the same way again.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blockIt">
        <img class="margins diagrams" id="diagramOne" src="images/diagramOne.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="blockIt">
        <img class="margins diagrams" id="diagramTwo" src="images/diagramTwo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
        <img id="walkieTalkieOne" alt="UWP-D11" src="images/walkieOne.jpg">
        <p class="infoHeader">UWP-D11</p>
        <p class="infoDesc">Is well suited for a wide range of applications, from news gathering and interviews to talk shows and conferences.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
        <img id="walkieTalkieTwo" alt="UWP-D12" src="images/walkieTwo.jpg">
        <p class="infoHeader">UWP-D12</p>
        <p class="infoDesc">Is widely used for interviews and news gathering and features a newly designed handheld transmitter.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
        <img id="walkieTalkieThree" alt="UWP-D16" src="images/walkieThree.jpg">
        <p class="infoHeader">UWP-D16</p>
        <p class="infoDesc">Is ideal for interviews and news gathering and features UTX-P03 plug-on bodypack transmitter.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="closer margins">Contact your Sony authorized reseller today and and discover the high-quality sound of digital audio processing.</p>
    <a id="resellButtLink" href="http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/product-UWPD11/42"><img id="resellerButton" class="margins" alt="Find a Reseller" src="images/button.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, IDs are not like classes..

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: I thought you called IDs in CSS with a hash tag before them though. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. Could you clarify?

Comment: You've put class `blockIt` in the `id` attribute on the line 204

Comment: Gotcha. I fixed it but the problem isn't resolved.

Comment: Sorry Felix, I'm not sure I know what that means. I'm fairly new to this stuff. This is my first Web Development job. Is balancing a good thing or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browsers are rendering just fine maybe it is because they know you don't have to close a `<p>` or something like this, and your text editor does not know it.. Try closing everything or changing the doctype inside your editor configuration.
Firefox has a good feature when viewing the code, it paints problematic tags in red.

Also, you have two class declaration at `<div class="introText" class="margins">`

Comment: Thanks for this tip though. It helped me narrow down the tags very quickly. It's still resolving in a weird way though.

Comment: When I click on the very last closing div tag, it says it resolves somewhere in the middle of the page. Well at least it's not throwing errors anymore I guess. I'll work with the formatting and ignore that for now. Thanks.

Comment: Alright well that's good enough for me then. Maybe it's just my machine. Thanks, enapupe. I appreciate your help. And thanks everybody for taking a look at it for me.

Answer (score 2):

`<div id="blockIt secondaryText">` on line 204 
I think it should have been 
`<div class="blockIt" id="secondaryText">`
Also, line 174

`<div class="introText" class="margins">`
should be 
`<div class="introText margins">`

Not closed `<p>` tags on lines 186&187

Answer (score 0):

You aren't posting your encoding. If you're using strict html encoding you have to close your img tags also [ex: `<img src="" alt="" />`]. I've seen in your update that you closed all the p tags. Maybe this is all that's left to do.